# Youtube - не воспроизводится видео на стороннем сайте

Tags: видео, youtube

Такая проблема, создан аккаунт, в него закинуты два видео, свои видео, галочка с разрешением поставлена, а во iframe на другом сайте предупреждение "это видео содержит материалы, принадлежащие пользователю WMG", ок, хорошо, я создал еще один аккаунт, в этом аккаунте мое видео уже принадлежит Sony, ну либо umg какому то, в зависимости от того, сколько раз f5 нажать, они рандомно меняются, никаких предупреждений в аккаунте нет, если на youtube вход выполнен, то видео прекрасно проигрываются, кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, сталкивались. Правообладатель запретил просмотр видео на сторонних ресурсах.

Comment: А кто правообладатель? У меня подобная ситуация, видео с только что созданного канала ютуб не воспроизводится на моем сайте, с ссылкой на владельца видео. На канале к данному видео доступ установлен открытый. Подскажите, что делать?